# Undefined members discord

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've had the same script so far to show members of any type
Online, offline and to a certain degree
It hasn't worked for a few hours
Do you think he made a discordant update for that?
I use discord.js@v11.6.4

```
const guild = bot.guilds.get("");
    setInterval(function () {
        var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;  
        var memberCountChannel = bot.channels.get("");
        memberCountChannel.setName(`Member count: ${memberCount}`);
    }, 1000);

    setInterval(function () {
        let onlineMembersCount =  guild.members.filter(member => member.presence.status !== "offline").size;
        var memberCountChannel = bot.channels.get("");
        memberCountChannel.setName(`Online members: ${onlineMembersCount}`);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors from it? Is that a command or triggered by event?

Comment: "does not work" is not sufficient information to provide to receive help.
What's the expected (wanted) behaviour, what's the actual (unwanted) behaviour? Do you get any errors? What's your relevant code that might be causing the issue?

Comment: Do you have the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent enabled?

Comment: Not even a mistake, nothing.
Suddenly I can't display the members anymore

Comment: And it's weird that it worked so far, suddenly it doesn't work at all

Comment: It`s possible because I use v11.6.4?

Comment: I know you are not using discord.py. But it is also described here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents There was some change in the API. Have you enabled getting member activity updates in your Discord API?